# can't access strong property inside block

Tags: ios

I have a strong property  NSMutableArray entries,when I am assigning some value it is showing null.Here is my code

```
#import "parseOperation.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *entries;

@end
```

////////
    AppDelegate.m

```
 __weak parseOperation *weakParser = parser;

parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {

    if (weakParser.appRecordList) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList%@",weakParser.appRecordList);//showing proper result

            self.entries=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            self.entries=weakParser.appRecordList;
            NSLog(@"self.entries=====%@",self.entries);//getting null value

        });
    }


    self.queue = nil;
};
```

Inside parser class if i print weakParser.appRecordList it always shows right result, but inside AppDelegate.m sometimes it's showing null.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha still not working

Answer (score 0):

Make it

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __block NSMutableArray *entries;
```

Otherwise it's just a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
        self.entries=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithArray: weakParser.appRecordList];
```